# How to hide a html table until letters have been typed in a search bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

So I want a html table to only show when the user has typed 1 or more letters in an input. So far what I have tried hasn't worked. Here's the html(i haven't included my full table):

```
        <input type="text" id="schoolName" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Search for names..">
        <table class="table">
        <thead><tr>
        <th title="Field #1">Official Name</th>
        <th title="Field #2">Local Name</th>
        <th title="Field #3">Address 1</th>
        <th title="Field #4">Address 2</th>
        <th title="Field #5">Address 3</th>
        <th title="Field #6">Address 4</th>
        <th title="Field #7">County</th>
        </tr></thead>
```

here's the js:

```
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener(search);
function search() {
if(document.getElementById("schoolName").value.length>1) {
    document.getElementById("table").style.visibility="visible";
 } else {
    document.getElementById("table").style.visibility="hidden";
 }
}
```

here's the css:

```
.table{
visibility: hidden;
display: block;
height: 150px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```

I don't know know how to make this work, thank you for the help

Comment: `getElementById("search")` - You don't have an element with that ID.  `getElementById("table")` - Or that one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Also changed the `id` in `getElementById` to one that is actually in your code, and gave `table` an `id`.

```js
document.getElementById("schoolName").addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (document.getElementById("schoolName").value.length > 1) {
    document.getElementById("table1").style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("table1").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="schoolName" placeholder="Search for names..">
<table id="table1" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th title="Field #1">Official Name</th>
      <th title="Field #2">Local Name</th>
      <th title="Field #3">Address 1</th>
      <th title="Field #4">Address 2</th>
      <th title="Field #5">Address 3</th>
      <th title="Field #6">Address 4</th>
      <th title="Field #7">County</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```